# How to parse a JSON document in Android?

Tags: android, json

I am trying parse this JSON.

The JSON Response [here](https://www.mangaeden.com/api/list/0/?p=1)

I am not getting full JSON data in the log cat just the link

**AsyncTask**

```
public class FetchMangaTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String[]>{


    private final String LOG_TAG = FetchMangaTask.class.getSimpleName();


    private String[] getMangaDataFromJson(String mangaJsonStr, int pages) throws JSONException{


        final String MANGA_LIST = "manga";
        final String MANGA_TITLE = "t";
        final String MANGA_ID = "i";

        JSONObject mangaJson = new JSONObject(mangaJsonStr);
        JSONArray mangaArray = mangaJson.getJSONArray(MANGA_LIST);

        String[] resultStr = new String[pages];
        for (int i = 0; i <mangaArray.length(); i++){


            JSONObject manga = mangaArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String title = manga.getString(MANGA_TITLE);
            String id = manga.getString(MANGA_ID);

        }

        for (String s : resultStr){
            Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Manga Entry" + s);
        }

        return resultStr;

    }


    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {

        if (params.length == 0){
            return null;
        }


        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        String mangaJsonStr = null;

        int pages = 1;



        try {

            final String MANGA_BASE_URL = "https://www.mangaeden.com/api/list/0/?";
            final String PAGES_PARAM = "p";

            Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(MANGA_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter(PAGES_PARAM, Integer.toString(pages))
                    .build();

            URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());

            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Built URI " + builtUri.toString());

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null){
                return null;
            }

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));


            String line;
            while ((line =  reader.readLine())!= null){

                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if (buffer.length() == 0){
                return null;
            }
            mangaJsonStr = buffer.toString();

        }catch (IOException e){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error", e);
            return null;
        }finally {
            if (urlConnection != null){
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null){
                try{
                    reader.close();
                }catch (final IOException e){
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }

              try {
            return getMangaDataFromJson(mangaJsonStr, pages);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
           Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
           e.printStackTrace();
           }
        }


        return null;
    }
}
```

I am only getting this in the log cat in Android Studio

**Log cat**

```
11-09 13:08:48.859 675-675/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
11-09 13:08:48.891 675-691/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
11-09 13:08:49.286 675-675/? I/LoadedApk: No resource references to update in package common
11-09 13:08:49.287 675-675/? I/LoadedApk: No resource references to update in package com.cyngn.yu
11-09 13:08:49.411 675-755/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
11-09 13:08:49.417 675-675/? D/Atlas: Validating map...
11-09 13:08:49.459 675-755/? I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BR.1.1.3_RB1.05.01.00.032.017_msm8916_64_LA.BR.1.1.3_RB1__release_AU (Iac7c2e2837)
11-09 13:08:49.459 675-755/? I/Adreno-EGL: OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.04
11-09 13:08:49.459 675-755/? I/Adreno-EGL: Build Date: 06/11/15 Thu
11-09 13:08:49.459 675-755/? I/Adreno-EGL: Local Branch: mybranch10882158
11-09 13:08:49.459 675-755/? I/Adreno-EGL: Remote Branch: quic/LA.BR.1.1.3_rb1.16
  11-09 13:08:49.459 675-755/? I/Adreno-EGL: Local Patches: NONE
 11-09 13:08:49.459 675-755/? I/Adreno-EGL: Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BR.1.1.3_RB1.05.01.00.032.017 + 26a3cba + 6f69ea6 + 8bc2bc8 + 649fcde + a52cccf + dbf281f + 15f0bf8 + 8d02f76 + 9b2cb1a + 25f3b04 + 7cd8c84 + b54906e + 675fd74 + 7c22ef4 +  NOTHING
 11-09 13:08:49.460 675-755/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
 11-09 13:08:49.471 675-755/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
 11-09 13:08:49.474 675-755/? I/qdutils: PartialUpdate status: Disabled
 11-09 13:08:49.474 675-755/? I/qdutils: Left Align: 0
 11-09 13:08:49.474 675-755/? I/qdutils: Width Align: 0
 11-09 13:08:49.474 675-755/? I/qdutils: Top Align: 0
 11-09 13:08:49.474 675-755/? I/qdutils: Height Align: 0
 11-09 13:08:49.474 675-755/? I/qdutils: Min ROI Width: 0
 11-09 13:08:49.474 675-755/? I/qdutils: Min ROI Height: 0
 11-09 13:08:49.474 675-755/? I/qdutils: Needs ROI Merge: 0
 11-09 13:08:49.474 675-755/? I/qdutils: Dynamic Fps: Disabled
 11-09 13:08:49.474 675-755/? I/qdutils: Min Panel fps: 0
 11-09 13:08:49.474 675-755/? I/qdutils: Max Panel fps: 0
 11-09 13:08:49.580 675-675/? I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@77a831a time:12438245
 11-09 13:08:49.688 675-675/? I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@77a831a time:12438353
 11-09 13:08:53.757 675-675/xyz.tahademure.purplereader W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.internal.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
 11-09 13:08:54.069 675-976/xyz.tahademure.purplereader V/FetchMangaTask: Built URI https://www.mangaeden.com/api/list/0/?p=1
 11-09 13:08:55.951 675-976/xyz.tahademure.purplereader V/FetchMangaTask: Manga Entrynull
```

Comment: To get all JSON string in log use `Log.i("TAG",mangaJsonStr);`

Comment: Looks like you getting more in Log Cat.

Comment: @eric247 updated fulll Log Cat

Comment: Try this, in the end of your doInBackground, add this, Log.v("Response",mangaJsonStr);

Comment: @ssh updated fulll Log Cat

Comment: @eric247 same result with Log.v("Response",mangaJsonStr);

Comment: can you print `mangaJsonStr`?

Comment: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ use this to simply your parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to you always make class structure of your JSON.
Class Page encapsulated each Page in your JSON. You can add also add meta to JSONParser class to control of loading.

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * @autor Sergey Shustikov (sergey.shustikov@agileengine.com)
 */
public class JSONParser {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = JSONParser.class.getSimpleName();

    public interface PageCallback {
        void onPagesReceived(ArrayList<Page> pages);

        void onFail();
    }

    public class Page {
        public String a;
        public ArrayList<String> c;
        public String h;
        public String id;
        public String im;
        public String ld;
        public String s;
        public String title;
    }

    public void loadPages(final int pageIndex, final PageCallback callback) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                load(pageIndex, callback);
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private void load(int pageIndex, PageCallback callback) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        String mangaJsonStr = null;

        int pages = pageIndex;


        try {

            final String MANGA_BASE_URL = "https://www.mangaeden.com/api/list/0/?";
            final String PAGES_PARAM = "p";

            Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(MANGA_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter(PAGES_PARAM, Integer.toString(pages))
                    .build();

            URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());

            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Built URI " + builtUri.toString());

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));


            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            mangaJsonStr = buffer.toString();
            try {
                ArrayList<Page> pgs = getPages(mangaJsonStr);
                callback.onPagesReceived(pgs);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                callback.onFail();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error", e);
            callback.onFail();
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private ArrayList<Page> getPages(String mangaJsonStr) throws JSONException {
        final String MANGA_LIST = "manga";
        final String MANGA_TITLE = "t";
        final String MANGA_ID = "i";

        JSONObject mangaJson = new JSONObject(mangaJsonStr);
        JSONArray mangaArray = mangaJson.getJSONArray(MANGA_LIST);

        ArrayList<Page> pages = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < mangaArray.length(); i++) {


            JSONObject manga = mangaArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String title = manga.getString(MANGA_TITLE);
            String id = manga.getString(MANGA_ID);
            Page page = new Page();
            page.title = title;
            page.id = id;
            pages.add(page);
        }
        return pages;
    }
}
```

To load :

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
parser.loadPages(1, new JSONParser.PageCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPagesReceived(ArrayList<JSONParser.Page> pages) {
                System.out.println(pages.size());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFail() {

            }
        });
```

Comment: @TahaDemure when you want to load. But i need to note : `onPagesReceived` will be called in Background thread, so if you want to update your UI use `post` or `runOnUIThread` methanism.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String[] resultStr = new String[pages];
    for (int i = 0; i <mangaArray.length(); i++){


        JSONObject manga = mangaArray.getJSONObject(i);

        String title = manga.getString(MANGA_TITLE);
        String id = manga.getString(MANGA_ID);

    }

    for (String s : resultStr){
        Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Manga Entry" + s);
    }
```

You're never setting anything in resultStr. I'm guessing you'd want something like this:

```
    String[] resultStr = new String[pages];
    for (int i = 0; i <mangaArray.length(); i++){


        JSONObject manga = mangaArray.getJSONObject(i);

        String title = manga.getString(MANGA_TITLE);
        String id = manga.getString(MANGA_ID);

        if (i < pages){
            resultStr[i] = title;
        }

    }

    for (String s : resultStr){
        Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Manga Entry" + s);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You never put a value inside `resultStr`. Why you did you not log your entry or add a value to `resultStr` in the first loop ?

```
for (int i = 0; i <mangaArray.length(); i++){
    JSONObject manga = mangaArray.getJSONObject(i);

    String title = manga.getString(MANGA_TITLE);
    String id = manga.getString(MANGA_ID);

    //Log
    Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Manga Entry" + manga.toString());

    //Add value assuming i < pages
    resultStr[i] = manga.toString();
}
```